# Is it possible to tell whether two WeakReferences point to the same object in c# without requiring an unsafe context?

Tags: c#, comparison, weak-references

Say that I have two `WeakReference` instances and I want to see if they point to the same object or not. You could imagine two scenarios, one where both references point to the same object:

```
SomeClass a = 1;
var wr1 = new WeakReference(a);
var wr2 = new WeakReference(a);
```

and one where they don't:

```
SomeClass a = 1;
SomeClass b = 1;
var wr1 = new WeakReference(a);
var wr2 = new WeakReference(b);
```

Is there any way to determine whether they're pointing to the same object without dropping into an unsafe context? `WeakReference.GetHashCode()` returns different values in both cases and I can't find any other members that might be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Target property references to the underlying object.

Try this:

```
wr1.Target == wr2.Target
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail for structs and also potentially give false positives when the equality operator is overwritten in classes? I can use `System.Object.ReferenceEquals()` to get around the second problem but not the first.

Comment: Yes, you can use `ReferenceEquals`. For value types you should unbox them before compare. There are a lot of edge cases you should maintain. What problem do you want to solve using this?

Comment: What I ultimately want to do is to compare the addresses of two value types, I just tried to make my question more general out of curiosity. I guess that I was kind of hoping that `WeakReference` could be used as kind of safe pointer. If I make a `WeakReference` to one value type and then later on make one to a second then I want to know if they share the same address, even if the first is no longer alive. This is trivial with pointers but I'm not sure if it's possible in a safe context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create own wrapper for the `WeakReference` with overloaded operator. Like this:

```
    public interface IWeakReferenceDecorator<T> where T : class
    {
        public void SetTarget(T target);
        public bool TryGetTarget(out T target);
    }

    public class TransientWeakReference<T> : IWeakReferenceDecorator<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly WeakReference<T> _weakReference;
        
        public TransientWeakReference(T target)
        {
            _weakReference = new WeakReference<T>(target);
        }

        public TransientWeakReference(T target, bool trackResurrection)
        {
            _weakReference = new WeakReference<T>(target, trackResurrection);
        }

        public TransientWeakReference(WeakReference<T> weakReference)
        {
            _weakReference = weakReference;
        }

        public void SetTarget(T target)
        {
            _weakReference.SetTarget(target);
        }

        public bool TryGetTarget(out T target)
        {
            return _weakReference.TryGetTarget(out target);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(TransientWeakReference<T> ref1, TransientWeakReference<T> ref2)
        {
            if (ref1 is null && ref2 is null)
                return true;
            return ref1 is not null &&
                   ref2 is not null &&
                   ref1._weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var target1) &&
                   ref2._weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var target2) &&
                   target1 == target2;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(TransientWeakReference<T> ref1, TransientWeakReference<T> ref2)
        {
            return !(ref1 == ref2);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj != null && GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
        }
        
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (_weakReference != null && _weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var target) ? target.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
```

This exapble doesn't work with Serialization, because it doesn't inherint `ISerializable`. So if you also need to serialize such object, then add correct using of `ISerializable` interface